# Adding ng-href to a button in angularjs changes the position of the text inside the button

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I'm starting to learn Angularjs (using angular-material), and I have a little problem using ng-href.
I made a Toolbar at the top of my web page, but as soon as I add the "ng-href" attribute to a button, the Text inside the Button isn't centered anymore:

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2OFp.png)

The first 2 Buttons have the ng-href tag added. The third one hasn't. Otherwise, they are exactly the same.

```js
angular.module('angular2',['ngRoute','ngMaterial','ngMessages'])
    .config(function ($mdThemingProvider,$routeProvider) {
        $mdThemingProvider.theme('default')
            .primaryPalette('blue')
            .accentPalette('blue');
        $routeProvider
            .when("/", {
                templateUrl : "main.html"
            })
            .when("/test1", {
                templateUrl : "test1.html"
            })
            .when("/test2", {
                templateUrl : "test2.html"
            })
    })
    .controller('mainCtrl',function ($scope, $http, $mdDialog) {

    })
    ;
```

```css
.navButton{
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0px;
    height: inherit;
    width: 150px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    text-transform: none;
    border: solid;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="angular2">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Angular 2</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700,400italic">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">


    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
<div layout="column">
    <md-toolbar class="md-menu-toolbar" style="height: 64px">
        <div layout="row" style="height: inherit">
            <md-toolbar-filler flex="5" style="height: inherit" layout layout-align="center center">
                <md-icon class="material-icons md" style="font-size: 48px; height: 48px; width: 48px">mail_outline
                </md-icon>
            </md-toolbar-filler>
            <div flex layout="row" layout-align="start center" style="height: inherit">
                <md-button class="md-primary navButton" ng-href="#/">Main</md-button>
                <md-button class="md-primary navButton" ng-href="#/test1">Test 1</md-button>
                <md-button class="md-primary navButton">Test 2</md-button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </md-toolbar>
    <div ng-view></div>
</div>


</body>

</html>
```

Somehow I couldn't manage to center the Text inside the Buttons after I added the ng-href attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't get a fiddle to recreate this. But I played with the md-button directive and normally it works fine for this.   There is potentially something in your app.css that is conflicting.

When md-button sees an href or ng-href, it will create an `<a>` tag and put your button content into a `<span>`.  So your

```
<md-button class="md-primary navButton" ng-href="#/test1">Test 1</md-button>
```

becomes

```
<a class="md-primary navButton md-button md-ink-ripple" 
        ng-transclude="" ng-href="#/test1" href="#/test1">
    <span class="ng-scope">Test 1</span>
</a>
```

angular-material.css gives that `<a>` tag a text-align:center, so check your CSS for something that is changing the attributes of the `<span>` when it's within `<a>`.

Here's the Fiddle I was working with but isn't exactly the same as yours: https://jsfiddle.net/phanxo14/

Comment: thanks. this actually helped me to solve the problem, as i wrote in the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

I kind of managed to fix the Problem:
Instead of using the md-button, that anuglarjs later turned into an `<a>` tag I copied the `<a>` tag that angular generated instead and used that one directly:

```
<a class="md-primary navButton md-button md-ink-ripple" ng-transclude="" ng-href="#/" style="text-align: center; height:inherit" href="#/" layout>
    <span class="ng-scope" flex style="text-align: center">Main</span>
</a>
```

Then I added the "layout" attribute to the surrounding `<a>` tag and the "flex" attribute to the inner `<span>`.
I acutally have no idea why this works, but the Text is now centered.

Edit: A Better and much easier fix was actually to just add the `layout` 
and `layout-align="center center"` attributes to the button.